# Zizaco/Entrust multiple method filters

Tags: laravel-5, entrust

I need to give `admin` access to all methods in controller, but only to some for `customer-admin`.

I tried to go with this

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('role:customer-admin')->only(['show', 'edit', 'update', 'upload_picture']); // should give access to select methods
    $this->middleware('role:admin'); // should give access to all methods
}
```

But it seems that in this case you have to conform to both.

Answer (score 0):

As counterintitive it may seem, here you have to combine roles based on methods. So the right answer would be:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('role:customer-admin|admin')->only(['show', 'edit', 'update', 'upload_picture']);
    $this->middleware('role:admin')->only(['index', 'create', 'store', 'destroy]); //Indicate methods that are exlusive to admin
}
```